# Figure credits misnumbering in tuftebook with {figure*}

Tags: floats

I'm writing a large book in `tuftebook` (TeXShop, MacOS) with a "home" .tex file (`PaP.tex`) that includes calls for individual chapters (`\include{PaPCh1}`, `\include{PaPCh2}`...).  (This likely has nothing to do with my problem.)

The very first figure in `PaP.tex` is full page, and hence is called using `figure*`:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{figure*} \label{fig:MyFirstFig} 
\includegraphics[...]
\caption{...}
\figurecredit{My figure credit.}
\end{figure*}
\end{fullwidth}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
```

Notice I had to set the counter before (`\setcounter{figure}{0}`) and after (`\setcounter{figure}{1}`) by hand to ensure (for some unknown reason) that the *ListOfFigures* gives the correct numbering (i.e., that this first figure is assigned number 1).

Fine.

The problem arises in the *Figure credits* page.  This first figure is assigned the number 0 (not 1).  How do I fix that?

I *think* the problem stems from either figure numbering not being incremented by this `figure*` (while it is fine for traditional `figure`s), or that the `\figurecredit{}` line should appear somewhere else.  Or yet some other mixup.

I'm happy to address this problem "by hand"... inserting some counter as needed.

---

***Solution*** (for others who confront this problem):

Put the `\figurecredit{}` line *WITHIN* the figure caption.